# How to anonymize SVN Dump

Tags: svn, dump, svnadmin, anonymize

In France it's important to respect privacy in order to deal with CNIL recommandations.

SVN property `svn:author` keep a trace of every person who has commited changes on the repository.

The Cnil's recommandations preconize to anonymize the information especially when time as passed and the information is no more interessant.

Svn's server tools comes with `svnadmin` and `svndumpfilter` but none of these can process svn:author properties.

`svn propset` fonctionality can only deal with a local checkout of the repository.
[More about svn propset](http://home.introweb.nl/d/dodger/svnauthor.html)

Answer (score 3):

[SVN Dump Tool](http://svn.borg.ch/svndumptool/) is a python tool that handle SVN Version 2 dump.

A typical command to anonymize a dump is :

```
# svndumptool.py transform-prop svn:author regexpToCatchSpecificAuthor newAuthorString from.svndump to.svndump
svndumptool.py transform-prop svn:author '.*' '' from.svndump to.svndump
```